# Xcopy Directory with folders

Tags: file, copy, directory, xcopy

I am doing an assignment for a class in cmd and I cant seem to figure something out.
**I need to:**

```
xcopy C:\"Romeo and Juliet" C:\BACKUP3\Blue
```

But I do not get anything, I usually use /S and /E but those don't seem to work.
**I Need:**

```
C:\BACKUP3\Blue\"Romeo and Juliet"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to put any quotes I guess.  Just a simple command for Xcopy:

```
xcopy C:\Romeo and Juliet /E C:\BACKUP3\Blue
```

Don't use both `/S` and `/E`:

- `/E` tag: it will copy sub directories as well as empty directories.
- `/S` tag: it will copy sub directories but not empty directories.